# How to autogenerate UUID for Postgres in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, uuid

I'm trying to create objects in Postgres db.

I'm using this approach https://websauna.org/docs/narrative/modelling/models.html#uuid-primary-keys

```
class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    # Pass `binary=False` to fallback to CHAR instead of BINARY
    id = sa.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True)
```

But when I create object

```
user_role = Role(name='User')
db.session.add(user_role)
db.session.commit()
```

I have the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Looks like I didn't provide any ID. So, how I can make the database auto-generate it or generate on my own?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask-Sqlalchemy, Primary key for secondary table in many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340380/flask-sqlalchemy-primary-key-for-secondary-table-in-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You appear to be using [this code](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#sqlalchemy_utils.types.uuid.UUIDType). It's missing a default for the column. You're emulating this SQL:

```
id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
```

But you've already [linked to the correct code](https://websauna.org/docs/narrative/modelling/models.html#uuid-primary-keys).

```
id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),
    primary_key=True,
    server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"),)
```

Alternatively if you don't want to load a Postgres UUID extension, you can create the UUIDs in Python.

```
from uuid import uuid4

id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),
    primary_key=True,
    default=uuid4,)
```

Comment: For Postgres 13+ we no longer need to use the `uuid-ossp` extension and can instead use the built-in `gen_random_uuid()`

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `uuid` module and just set a column default. For example:

```
from uuid import uuid4
from sqlalchemy import Column, String

class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
```

Comment: If you are looking to use the PostgreSQL UUID type (which I believe has some performance advantages), see the answer from @Schwern.

Answer (score 3):

What I actually came to is:

```py
import uuid

class SomeClass(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'someclass'

    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),
        primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
import uuid

myId = uuid.uuid4()
print(myId)
```