# SQLAlchemy - Default PKs and Bulk Save

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a model with a uuid as the pk with a default value like so:

```py
class Car(...):
    ...
    uuid = Column(
        String, 
        primary_key=True, 
        default=lambda x: str(uuid4()),
    )
```

At somepoint in my application I bulk add a bunch of `Cars` like so:

```py
# create a list of `Car` instances from raw data:
cars = [Car(**car) for car in raw_cars_data]

# bulk insert:
session.bulk_save_objects(cars)
session.commit()

# try to access pks:
for car in cars:
    print(car.uuid)  # <-- this is `None`
```

I am trying to get the pk for the cars that were bulk created, the pks were set using the `default` method. However, the pk on each `Car` in the `cars` array is `None`. How can I retrieve the pks of the cars that were created?

Note, if I do a single create operation the pk is successfully retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects) you should use the `return_defaults` argument. As mentionned, it will lead to performance loss (depending of number of rows you have).

Most ORMs will not by default execute defaults values.

One way to tackle that is by declaring the primary key default as a database function, so the UUID is generated in the database side.

For example, in postgres with sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
```

Comment: what would the implementation look like with UUID from postges?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071275/10034177 might help you.

Comment: Another way to deal with all of that is using sqlalchemy utils package which allow to have a generic UUID field, which use the postures dialect if you are using a postures database.