# sqlalchemy many to many relationships (the value of a duplicate key breaks the unique constraint) flask_user role

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

can you help me,

when i run this script it works well

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='1')

    # User authentication information. The collation='NOCASE' is required
    # to search case insensitively when USER_IFIND_MODE is 'nocase_collation'.
    email = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email_confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # User information
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, server_default='')
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, server_default='')

    # Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles')

# Define the Role data-model
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

# Define the UserRoles association table
class UserRoles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('roles.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

# Setup Flask-User and specify the User data-model
user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)

# Create all database tables
db.create_all()

# Create 'member@example.com' user with no roles
if not User.query.filter(User.email == 'member@example.com').first():
    user = User(
        email='member@example.com',
        email_confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        password=user_manager.hash_password('Password1'),
    )
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

# Create 'admin@example.com' user with 'Admin' and 'Agent' roles
if not User.query.filter(User.email == 'admin@example.com').first():
    user = User(
        email='admin@example.com',
        email_confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        password=user_manager.hash_password('Password1'),
    )
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Admin'))
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Agent'))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

at this stage the code is working without problems but the problem is just after when I add another user with a role that already exists
in this case the Admin role or the Agent role
for example if I add the code below an error message displays

```
    if not User.query.filter(User.email == 'admin2@example.com').first():
    user = User(
        email='admin2@example.com',
        email_confirmed_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        password=user_manager.hash_password('Password1'),
    )
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Admin'))
    user.roles.append(Role(name='Agent'))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) ERREUR:  la valeur d'une clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « roles_name_key »
>   DETAIL:  La clé « (name)=(Admin) » existe déjà.
>    [SQL: 'INSERT INTO roles (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING roles.id'] [parameters: {'name': 'Admin'}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.
>   me/e/gkpj)

I tried db driver different (pg8000, pygresql, py-postgresql) and still the same problem,

as the error message shows the problem because of the name value which is unique

name = db.Column (db.String (50), unique = True)

can you explain to me what is the error that I made, and what is the role of this part of code

```
# Define the relationship to Role via UserRoles

roles = db.relationship ('Role', secondary = 'user_roles')
```

I use flask with flask_user

Comment: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/ advises against using a model for the helper table: `If you want to use many-to-many relationships you will need to define a helper table that is used for the relationship. For this helper table it is strongly recommended to not use a model but an actual table`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask-Sqlalchemy, Primary key for secondary table in many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30340380/flask-sqlalchemy-primary-key-for-secondary-table-in-many-to-many-relationship)